# Is there an equivalent of Rails ActiveRecord::Callbacks in ASP MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Is there an equivalent of Rails ActiveRecord::Callbacks in ASP MVC?

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

I'm in a situation where we are not using identities for our primary key.  We do this for reasons specific to our DB sharding design.  Because of this we have a lookup table to find the next ID for a specific table.  I'd like to automatically get this value and set it in an abstract class whenever a model is created/updated and before it is saved.  I also need to update the lookup table with an incremented 'nextID' after the save is successful.

I'm open to other solutions on how to do this without callbacks as well.

Comment: yes, but not exactly the same way. What you want is Lazy Loading. Entity Framework supports Lazy Loading. It requires you to pass attached models and make db context available.

Comment: I understand the concept of lazy loading, but I'm not sure how that would hep with this issue.  Could you provide a quick example of your solution?

Comment: Sorry, just saw this. Lazy Loading is an overly simplistic take on this. asp.net doesn't have anything comparable to the call-backs that active record has. On the other hand, this can be substituted for with Helpers or Ajax events. The challenging part is making your dbcontext available in your View context. That is my focus on 'Lazy Loading'. again oversimplistic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using overrides as opposed to callbacks.  It's my hope that ASP mvc adds support for callbacks as the framework continues to mature because callbacks allow for cleaner code by allowing the OnSave event to exist in the model[s] that the event is concerned with rather than the centralized DbContext class (separation of concerns).

**Solution:**

The SaveChanges method can be overridden in the Context Class ([Entity Framework Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d) creates the Context class is the 'Models' directory).

```cs
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        // create a cache for id values in case their are multiple added entries in the dbcontext for the same entitytype
        Dictionary<string, UniqueID> idCache = new Dictionary<string, UniqueID>();
        IEnumerable<DbEntityEntry> changes = this.ChangeTracker.Entries();
        foreach (var entry in changes)
        {
            //check if this is a new row (do nothing if its only a row update because there is no id change)
            if (entry.State == System.Data.EntityState.Added)
            {
                //determine the table name and ID field (by convention)
                string tableName = entry.Entity.GetType().Name;
                string idField = entry.Entity.GetType().Name + "ID";
                UniqueID id = null;
                //if we've already looked this up, then use the cache
                if (idCache.ContainsKey(tableName))
                {
                    id = idCache[tableName];
                }
                //if we havn't looked this up before get it and add it to the cache
                else
                {
                    id = this.UniqueIDs.Find(tableName, idField);
                    //if it doesn't already exist in the lookup table create a new row
                    if (id == null)
                    {
                        id = new UniqueID(tableName, idField, 1);
                        // since this is a new entry add it
                        this.UniqueIDs.Add(id);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // set the state to modified
                        this.Entry(id).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
                    }
                }
                entry.CurrentValues[tableName + "ID"] = id.NextID;
                id.NextID = id.NextID + 1;
            }

        }
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So you need the callback just to increment ID in the lookup table? AFAIK there is no equivalent in ASP.NET, may be you could try with Async Controllers (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and wait for a state change from the successful save, but I would prefer use a service specifically for this like Snowflake (https://github.com/twitter/snowflake/).